# How do I give my dropdown-menu an inherited width of parent <li>-element?

Tags: css

I have a navigation bar made from an unordered list in HTML. Within my list I have another nested list which acts (or is supposed to act) as a dropdown-menu. I will let the markup speak for itself:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Produkter</a>
        <ul class="dropdowncontent">
            <li><a href="#">Moderkort</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Processorer</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Hårddiskar</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Grafikkort</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Butiker</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Kontakt</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vanliga frågor</a></li>
</ul>
```

First of all, I am wondering if I should be using a class (which I am currently doing), or if I should use an ID instead?

Secondly, I have issues with giving my dropdown-menu a width which I wish to be of the same width of the list-item "Produkter". Here is my CSS:

```
body {
margin:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
overflow:hidden;
background-color:black;
}

ul li {
float:left;
}

ul li a {
display:block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
padding:14px 16px;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
transition-duration:0.4s;
}

ul li a:hover {
background-color:#333;
}

ul li ul.dropdowncontent {

}
```

Notice that the CSS-selector of the dropdown-menu (a nested unordered list) is empty. This is because I simply don't know how to style it.

Help is much appreciated. Sincerely, Max.

Comment: With only css we cannot achieve what you want,like opening/closing list on clicking it. With the help of jquery/js we can do it.Could you please attach a screen shot of what you need?

Comment: It is possible with the CSS :hover-selector. This I don't have any problems with. Before implementing this function I want to make sure that the dropdown-menu looks good when always being displayed though.

Comment: What I want to achieve is inheriting the width of the parent element, so that the width of the dropdown-menu is the same as the list-item "Produkter". 

That will hopefully automatically make the list-items in the dropdown-menu appear beneath each other, in other words, vertically aligned.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my own question, but I would still like some input. This is what I did:

1. First, I gave my list-items a fixed width of 150px.

   ```
   ul li {
   float:left;
   width:150px;
   }
   ```

Then, I positioned my dropdown-menu as absolute (I don't know why this works, if someone please could explain this to me I would be very happy). Then, I gave the dropdown-menu the same width as my list-items. I also displayed the dropdown-menu as a block-level element. Here it is:

```
ul li ul.dropdowncontent {
position:absolute;
display:block;
width:150px;
font-size:80%;
}
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 0):

Try following CSS code, No need change your html structure.

```
body {
margin:0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

ul {
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
width:100%;
background-color:black;
min-height: 46px;
}

ul li {
float:left;
position: relative;
}

ul li a {
display:block;
color:white;
text-decoration:none;
text-align:center;
padding:14px 16px;
-webkit-transition-duration:0.4s;
transition-duration:0.4s;
}

ul li a:hover,
ul li:hover > a {
background-color:#333;
}

ul li ul.dropdowncontent {
position: absolute;
top: 100%;
left: 0;
width: 100%;
display: none;
background-color: #333;
min-width: 150px; // Added otherwise only with parent width dose not possible to show entire link text.
}
ul li:hover > ul.dropdowncontent {
display: block;
}
```